# Mailchimp removes CSS properties from <style> tag when replacing image in Content Studio

Tags: html, css, html-email, mailchimp

So basically I have some images inside my HTML email template which I want to replace them using their Content Studio. I've put inside `<img>` a `mc:edit` class and it looks like this :

```html
<img src="link_to_img" 
style="
margin: auto; 
padding: 0; 
max-width: 600px; 
width: 100%; 
display: block" 
mc:edit="image1">
```

But the problem is whenever I replace image using Content Studio (not inside  tag), img `<style>` doesn't preserve initial properties, like `max-width: 600px` is removed, which in fact affects the responsiveness. What could be the solution?

Comment: `max-width` will never apply as it is overwritten by by `width`. `max-width` should come after the `width`-property. So it properly removes the property to shorten the code.

Comment: I've already tried to add `max-width` the last property, but it behaves the same.

Comment: Just to clarify, I think your question should say "from style attribute" rather than "from `<style>` tag" because we're not in fact referring to the `<style>` block in the `<head>`. Is that right?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tags-vs-elements-vs-attributes-in-html/

Comment: Does a class work like this mailchimp reference suggests? https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/responsive-email/fluid-images/

Comment: Try adding it to the head of he document. Mailchimp inlines CSS you have before sending.